# FullCalendar and qTip UI issue when dragging event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, qtip, qtip2

When **dragging an event** in week or day view. Randomly, qtips would be rendered with the old ones being still on the screen.

[image]

I have been disabling the qtips using apis but no result whatsoever. Following is my qtip configuration for fullcalendar event render event:

```
eventRender = function (event, element) {
    $(element).qtip(
        {
            content: '<div>Hello, World!</div>',
            position: {
                target: 'mouse', // Track the mouse as the positioning target
                adjust: { x: 5, y: 5 } // Offset it slightly from under the mouse
            },
            style: 'qtip-light'
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ibrahim, Use eventAfterRender function. It works for me.

```
eventAfterRender: function( event, element, view ) {
    $(element).qtip(
    {
        content: '<div>Hello, World!</div>',
        position: {
            target: 'mouse', // Track the mouse as the positioning target
            adjust: { x: 5, y: 5 } // Offset it slightly from under the mouse
        },
        style: 'qtip-light'
    });
}
```